# How to check whether a linear map on integral domains is a formal derivative

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, derivatives

I have an elementary question on formal derivatives.
Assume $A=K[X,Y,Z]/I$ is an integral domain (for example $I$ is a prime ideal
and K is the field of rationals). 
Let $d:A\to A$ be a linear map. Is there a standard test to check whether $d$ is a formal derivative (i.e. satisfies Leibniz rule 
$d(a\cdot b)=d(a)\cdot b+d(b)\cdot a$)? I imagine one has to check that $d(p(X,Y,Z))=0$ for $p(X,Y,Z)$ a polynomial in I. Is this necessary and sufficient? Are there other tests?

Comment: You mean besides just doing it? You're asking if there is some trick which reduces computations or something?

Comment: $p=0$ in $A$, so $d(p)=0$ holds in any case. Or do you start with a linear map on $K[X,Y,Z]$? To answer your question, look at the general formula of $\Omega^1_A$ in terms of a presentation of $A$.

Comment: to alex: yes I would like to know if there are standard tricks to reduce computations.

Comment: to Martin: can you give a reference text to look a these matters (not too advanced), thanks

Comment: to Martin: sorry I've been misleading, I mean that the map is defined in $K[x,y,z]$ and is linear and respects the Leibniz rule in $K[x,y,z]$, I would like to know when it survives as a derivation in the quotient ring.